# Find a set of values for x for a decreasing function

Tags: functions

Find a set of values of x for which $x^2-3x+4$ for a decreasing function.

So $x^2-3x+4 \leq 0$ and I am getting $x < \left(\frac {3}{2}\right) \pm {\sqrt {\left(\frac {-7}{4}\right)}}$

Can anyone tell me if its correct ?

I saw the answer and it was $x < 1.5$

Comment: A function is decreasing on an interval $I$ if $f'(x)<0$ for all $x\in I$.

Comment: What you are calculating is the range of x for which the function is non-positive. What you have to do instead is calculate the derivative of the function and find the range of x for which it is non-positive.

Comment: @user2369284 may I know how ?

Comment: @PeresCudd  Have you studied calculus?

Comment: The function decreases as long as its derivative is negative. This does not imply anything about the sign of the function itself.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig No.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici so I checked online for decreasing function, it says the y value decreases as the x value increases. So why is it $x<1.5$

Comment: @PeresCudd  You should edit your question to reflect what you now know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Definition.**  A function is *strictly decreasing* on an interval $I$ if for each $x_1, x_2 \in I$ such that $x_1 < x_2$, $f(x_1) > f(x_2)$.

Intuitively, what this means is that as the $x$-values increase, the $y$-values decrease.  On a graph, it means that the curve falls as you move to the right.

The graph of the function $f(x) = x^2 - 3x + 4$ is the parabola $y = x^2 - 3x + 4$, which opens upwards since the leading coefficient is positive.  Therefore, the function decreases to the left of the vertex, reaches its minimum value at the vertex, and increases to the right of the vertex.  We can determine the vertex by completing the square.

\begin{align*}
f(x) & = x^2 - 3x + 4\\
     & = (x^2 - 3x) + 4\\
     & = \left(x^2 - 3x + \frac{9}{4}\right) - \frac{9}{4} + 4\\
     & = \left(x - \frac{3}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{7}{4}
\end{align*}

Thus, the function has vertex $(\frac{3}{2}, \frac{7}{4})$, so the function is strictly decreasing if $x < \frac{3}{2}$, as you can see from the graph.

[image: graph_of_f(x)=x^2-3x+4]

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) So all i had to do was just find the vertex ?

Comment: The idea is to determine where the graph is falling as you move to the right.  Since the graph of the function is a parabola that opens upwards, the graph is falling to the left of the vertex, which is why I found the vertex of the parabola.